Using XML-RPC with Cookies in Java
I am trying to load data from a website using XML-RPC. This works quite well so far, but not on pages that require a login. I send my user name and password for this.
I know from a colleague that cookies are also required. Namely PHPSESSID and another one, let's call it OTHER_COOKIE ;)
I pull these from my browser.
However, I have not been able to actually use these cookies for two days now. I can't find a way to get the XmlRpcClient to take these cookies with it. I always get the answer that I do not have access to these pages. There are probably classes like XmlRpcTransport or similar which should be used for this, but I can't get any further. The documentation situation is horrible.
Here is the code that at least works for pages that don't require a login.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
(If it plays a role: The page I am trying to read is a ‘MoinMoinWiki’.)
    private final XmlRpcClient client;

    public MoinMoinWikiClient(String baseUrl, String username, String password) throws Exception {



        String endpointUrl = baseUrl + "/moinmoin/?action=xmlrpc2";

/*
 EDIT: I now realise that using a username and password here is insane. That's exactly what cookies are for. I only need them for a manual login to create the cookies. Sorry, that was a bit stupid of me
*/
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {
            @Override
            public String getBasicUserName() {
                return username;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBasicPassword() {
                return password;
            }
        };

        config.setServerURL(new URL(endpointUrl));

        this.client = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config);

        String examplePageName = "any_page";

        HashMap<String, Object> result = (HashMap<String, Object>)client.execute("getPageInfo", new Object[]{examplePageName});

        info("Initialized XML-RPC client with URL: " + xmlRpcEndpoint);

    }

I have been researching solutions and documentation for two days. I have asked ChatGPI for a long time and in detail ;)
Countless supposed solutions ended with the fact that the classes were not known and could not be added to Maven. e.g. CookieManager, CookiesStore ...
public MoinMoinWikiClient(String wikiUrl, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        String endpointUrl = wikiUrl + "/moinmoin/?action=xmlrpc2";

/*
 EDIT: I now realise that using a username and password here is insane. That's exactly what cookies are for. I only need them for a manual login to create the cookies. Sorry, that was a bit stupid of me
*/
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {
            @Override
            public String getBasicUserName() {
                return username;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBasicPassword() {
                return password;
            }
        };

        config.setServerURL(new URL(endpointUrl));

        BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        List<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
        cookies.add(new org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie("PHPSESSID", Main.PHPSESSID));
        cookies.add(new org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie("OTHER_COOKIE", Main.OTHER_COOKIE));
        cookieStore.addCookies(cookies.toArray(new Cookie[0]));

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .build();


        this.client = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config);
    }


"I pull these from my browser" - what does that mean? It kind of sounds like the cookies have simply expired.

Link to the XML RPC library you are using.

Gimby: "I pull these from my browser": I log in via my browser and read the value of the cookies. I can rule out the possibility that they have expired.
Basil: org.apache.xmlrpc (.client.XmlRpcClient / .client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl)org.apache.xmlrpc / artifactId: xmlrpc-client / v3.1.3

I finally made it...!
Here is the Code:
import com.hacon.wiki.moinmoin.Config;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class XmlRpcManager {
    private String domain;
    private List<Cookie> cookies;

    public XmlRpcManager(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.cookies = new ArrayList<>();

        cookies.add(new Cookie(".xxx.de", "PHPSESSID", Config.PHPSESSID, "/", null, true));
        cookies.add(new Cookie(".xxx.de", "XXXX_COOKIENAME", Config.XXXX_COOKIENAME, "/", null, true));

    }


    public List<String> getAllPages(String filter) {

        String xmlRpcUrl = "https://xxxxxx/moinmoin/?action=xmlrpc2";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                httpClient.getState().addCookie(new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie(
                        cookie.getDomain(),
                        cookie.getName(),
                        cookie.getValue(),
                        cookie.getPath(),
                        cookie.getExpiryDate(),
                        cookie.getSecure()
                ));
            }
        }

        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();

        try {
            config.setServerURL(new URL(xmlRpcUrl));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("bad url format >> " + xmlRpcUrl);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory factory = new XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory(client);
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        client.setTransportFactory(factory);
        client.setConfig(config);

        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = client.execute("getAllPages", new Object[]{});
        } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            System.err.println("failed");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Object[] pagesArray = (Object[]) result;


        List<String> pageNames = Arrays.stream(pagesArray)
                .map(Object::toString)
                .filter(s -> filter.isEmpty() || s.contains(filter))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Found: " + String.valueOf(pageNames.size()));

        return pageNames;
    }
}


This is what Stack Overflow refers to as a "code-only" answer which is a reason for answers to receive downvotes. Please try to add an explanation of what you changed to make it work and why.
